# Pod file is not creating in my Project?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode8

I am new to iOS. Now I am trying to work with CocoaPods. But for me Pod file is not creating in my project. When I type the following line like

```
"cd /Users/xxx/xxx/ProjectName"
It is coming like 
"Macname:ProjectName imfuser$"
```

after this When I wirte "Pod init"
It is not creating Pod file.

Error I am Getting is Like this :

````
――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod init
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.1.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
    RubyGems : 2.0.14.1
        Host : Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323)
       Xcode : 8.1 (8B62)
         Git : git version 2.9.3 (Apple Git-75)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 15a4461d3cead785c7dbce58908e4a38c8d3a9e0
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.1.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby

```

### Error

```
LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:23:in `read_from_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:200:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:102:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=cannot+load+such+file+--+nanaimo&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6214 [open] [18 comments]
   5 hours ago

 - help!   cannot load such file -- nanaimo
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6312 [closed] [4 comments]
   a week ago

 - LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6281 [closed] [2 comments]
   3 weeks ago

and 5 more at:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=cannot%20load%20such%20file%20--%20nanaimo&type=Issues&utf8=✓
````

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I have done.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what error you are getting...?

Comment: After pod init you have to fire another query "touch Podfile" then your pod file will create I think so.

Comment: install all gem of cocoapods first. execute sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: @NileshFasate No. It is not working even if I type that.

Comment: @Jecky First command I typed that it came like "1 gem installed" . After that only I am getting error.

Comment: please follow this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHtx99ODyb0 it help for me

Comment: this path has direct to .xcodeproject  then you can create pod file

Comment: First try to install your cocoa pod using **sudo gem install cocoapods --pre**

Comment: That command is not working "sudo gem install cocoapods --pre"

Comment: If I try that command also "workspace" is not creating.

Comment: Okay uninstall cocoa pod then run **sudo gem update --system** command and then install cocoa pod again 

It will work.

Comment: I am getting error while installing cocoa pods like

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod

Answer (score 11):

I have got the same error :

> #### Error
>
> `` LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:23:in
>   `read_from_path'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:200:in
>   `initialize_from_file'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:102:in
>   `open'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:851:in
>   `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:850:in
>   `each'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:850:in
>   `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in
>   `section'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:845:in
>   `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:66:in
>   `analyze'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:236:in
>   `analyze'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:150:in
>   `block in resolve_dependencies'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in
>   `section'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:149:in
>   `resolve_dependencies'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:110:in
>   `install!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in
>   `run'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in
>   `run'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in
>   `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/bin/pod:55:in
>   `<top (required)>' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
>   /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' ``

To solve this issue,firstly uninstall **all version** of nanaimo

> sudo gem uninstall nanaimo

[image]

Install (or reinstall) cocoapods

> sudo gem install cocoapods

[image]

After this, you can install your pods

> pod install

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem from having two versions of nanaimo installed. Try removing the oldest:

```
gem list | grep nanaimo
sudo gem uninstall nanaimo (then pick the version you want to remove)
```

Comment: Run this in terminal `sudo gem uninstall nanaimo` and remove old nanaimo version

Answer (score 2):

Install cocoa pod by this way. Write below code in terminal.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Before this also remove old version of nanaimo

```
sudo gem uninstall nanaimo
```

Comment: Remove old version of nanaimo